# Is there any reason not to perform rogue actions?

Tags: octopath-traveler

So far, my octopath party is the thief, Therion, and the hunter, H'aanit.  The game box says that both of their path actions are 'rogue' actions.  Are there any negative repercussions for stealing everything and attacking people for free money, xp, and items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rogue Path Actions have a chance of failing and can also damage your reputation if you keep failing. If your reputation takes too much of a dip, NPCs will no longer react to your Path Actions, and you’ll need to head to the local tavern keeper and hand over some Leaves (money) to bump that reputation back up. [Sauce.](https://twinfinite.net/2018/07/octopath-traveler-noble-rogue-path-actions-explained/)

Noble actions, on the other hand, have no negative repercussions. Both Rogue and Noble actions do NOT impact the storyline for each of the eight protagonists.

A primary reason to use one over the other is that sometimes you are not able to do one type of action, but can do another.

Comment: One thing worth mentioning is that sometimes you can _only_ do Rogue actions, and vice-versa.

Comment: This talks about negative repercussions on a failure, but nothing about successes.  If I never fail a rogue action, do I never have any negative consequences?

Comment: @Tal you will not get a dip to reputation if you do not fail a Rogue action, however in my playthrough it's not unusual to fail several times